# limit points of the set

Tags: general-topology

$X=\{a,b,c,d\},\tau$ be a topological space where $\tau=\phi,X,\{a\},\{ab\},\{ac\},\{abc\}$
I just need to know what are limit points of $S=\{a,c,d\}$

I think $a$ is the only limit point of $S$ as open neighborhood of $a$ intersection $S$ consists the point $a$, am I right?

and $b$ is also a limit point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is not any open balls of $d$ which is supposed to intersect $S$, then $d$ is a limit point. Checking the definition for other points are routine.

Comment: $c,d$ are limit points..

Comment: There is open ball of $d$ – the whole space.

Comment: Another limit point answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

$x$ is limit point of $S$ iff for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $S ∩ U \setminus \{x\} ≠ ∅$. So you have actually proved that $a$ is isolated. On the other hand any nbhd of any $b, c, d$ contains $a ∈ S$, so $b, c, d$ are limit points of $S$.